# Swiper nav buttons outside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to display the nav buttons outside the swiper container, because of the container overflow: hidden i had to create a wrap with position: relative and position the buttons absolutely.

That worked, the problem is that now the nav buttons control all sliders and i can't figure out a way to solve this.

I don't want to initialize multiple sliders with different classes if the slider is the same with different content.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmLLo1cn/)

```js
var sliderProdutosDestaque = new Swiper('.slider-produtos-destaque.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-prev',
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px 60px 40px;
}

.slider-produtos-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

.swiper-prev,
.swiper-next {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.swiper-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.swiper-next {
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-produtos-wrap">
  <div class="slider-produtos-destaque swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-next"></div>

</div>

<div class="slider-produtos-wrap">
  <div class="slider-produtos-destaque swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-next"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to loop through the elements that contain the slider container, and then grabbing the elements that are required (Swiper, Next Btn, Prev Btn) and using this in the setup for the Swiper.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-produtos-wrap");

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    var el = x[i];

  var swiper = el.getElementsByClassName("swiper-container")[0];
  var nx = el.getElementsByClassName("swiper-next")[0];
  var pr = el.getElementsByClassName("swiper-prev")[0];

  new Swiper(swiper, {
        slidesPerView: 2,  
        spaceBetween: 10,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: nx,
          prevEl: pr
        }
  });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmLLo1cn/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Easy, tiny and tidy.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-container').forEach(function(elem) {
  new Swiper(elem, {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: elem.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling,
      prevEl: elem.nextElementSibling,
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px 60px 40px;
}

.slider-produtos-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

.swiper-prev,
.swiper-next {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.swiper-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.swiper-next {
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-produtos-wrap">
  <div class="slider-produtos-destaque swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-next"></div>

</div>

<div class="slider-produtos-wrap">
  <div class="slider-produtos-destaque swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-next"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way for anyone that might find it useful. Pass in count as a props with a different value for each slider. I did count="1" and count="2". This gives each sliders navigation arrows a different class so they will work independently of each other

```
<div :class="'swiper-button-prev-' + count" slot="button-prev"></div>
<div :class="'swiper-button-next-' + count" slot="button-next"></div>

props: ['count'],
data() {
  return {
    swiperOption: {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 45,
    grabCursor: true,
    centerInsufficientSlides: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: `.swiper-button-next-${this.count}`,
      prevEl: `.swiper-button-prev-${this.count}`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely. Do you know if there is a way to disable the buttons if the slides are at the beginning or the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
.swiper-container::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 9;
}
.swiper-container::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```